# How can I choose the minimum range for each month with daterangepicker?

Tags: daterangepicker

Using this http://www.daterangepicker.com/

How can I choose the minimum selection for each month? For example I'm using this code;

```
$('.date-picker input').daterangepicker({
"minSpan": {
        "days": 5
    },
            showDropdowns: true,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            }
        });
```

I want this code like this;

```
$('.date-picker input').daterangepicker({

if(this.month==5){
"minSpan": {
        "days": 5
    },
}
            showDropdowns: true,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The pull request fixing this was not implemented yet, so you will have to change the source file by yourself. Install Date Range Picker via npm

[bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

Link the js-file in your html (if you are working with html)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Go to the daterangepicker.js file and add the missing code:

https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/pull/2173/files

Then your js code must work

```
$('.date-picker input').daterangepicker({
"minSpan": {
        "days": 5
    },
```